# get bitwise XOR product of range of consecutive numbers

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, bit-manipulation

> You are given two numbers `0<=M<N` and
>   have to retrieve the bitwise XOR product
>   of the numbers in range [M,N].
>
> example: given 3 numers A, B, C, the
>   bitwise XOR product is defined as
>   `A bitwiseXOR B bitwiseXOR C`

So bit `i` of the product the result of XOR-in all the bits of the numbers in the range at position `i`.

One more constraint, the algorithm has to work in logarithmic time.

My attempt to solving this was something in the lines of:

```
num_bits = log(max(M,N));

for(i=0;i<num_bits;i++)
{
    lsbM = M&1;
    lsbN = N&1;
    result |= bitwiseXor(lsbM,lsbN)<<1;
    M>>=1;
    N>>=1;
}
```

I just did not find the correct rule to write `int bitwiseXor(int lsbM, int lsbN)`.
This is **not** homework and it's not a "I need the solution in 2 hours because I have an interview" type of question. It's no more than a problem I decided to take a shot at.

**EDIT:**
example A = 8, B = 9, C = 10

```
    A:  1000
    B:  1001
    C:  1010
result  1011
```

bitwiseXor(lsbM,lsbN) returns the value of the bit at position i in the result

Comment: Do you realize that `^` does bitwise xor?

Comment: I think the important thing to note here is that every next number only a few bits change, try to exploit that.

Comment: @Shahbaz yes but I neet this in O(log(n)) not O(N); simply Xor-ing all the numbers will be O(n)

Comment: @Pandrei, I didn't mean that. I was just mentioning that the _function_ `bitwiseXor` is jut operator `^`.

Comment: @invalid_id I know only a few bits change, but did not find(yet) a general rule - that's why I asked the question

Comment: There is no implementation for `bitwiseXor` that fixes this problem - what you need is whether the number of times that the selected bit can be set in that range is odd or even, you can't extract from just the selected bits of the endpoints, you need the full endpoints.

Comment: This line looks rather strange: >>> result |= bitwiseXor(lsbM,lsbN)<<1; <<< The result is true as soon as one bitwiseXor is true?? And why the constant shift by one bit?? Please provide an example what the expected result should be for e.g. 8, 9, 10.

Comment: Your result will have the bit order reversed compared to your inputs (i.e. the most significant result bit relates to the XOR of the least significant input bits).  And your algo is O(log2N) already, assuming N is the range N-M, which is certainly what the questioner would have expected given a naive solution would iterate through that range XORing the values.  Sadly though, your algo produces the wrong results.  If you write that naive slow implementation and create a few test cases, you'll start to understand why... ;-).

Comment: One negative test case: for 1-5: in binary you have 001 010 011 100 101 -> lsb result should be '1' as there are three odd inputs with lsb set, not the '0' you get from XORing 001 and 101.

Comment: @TonyD thanks for pointing that out - you are correct; but the main focus of the question is how to write the bitwiseXOR function.

Comment: @laune That's a bitwise or, not a logical or.

Comment: @Pandrei: Shahbaz addressed that in the first comment: C and C++ provide the `^` operator that you can use like this: `(lsbM ^ lsbN)`.  If you were determined to write your own... `a | b` tells you all the bits either has, but for xor you don't want the ones they both have i.e. `a & b`, so `a ^ b` can also be written as `(a | b) & !(a & b)` or even `(a | b) - (a & b)` - beauty's in the eye of beholder.